# Unicode support in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am basically from VC++, for compiling a project with Unicode support we will change the setting in project properties and build it. In VB.net is there anything like that, Do I have to change any setting  before building to enable Unicode support.?

Comment: All .NET is unicode by default I think

Answer (score 5):

VB.Net always has full Unicode support in the language and runtime.

You can even use Unicode letters in identifiers.

Comment: Ok, It means I dont have to make any specific changes in project properties. Just directly build as usual. Correct..?